# Using JSON file in HTML: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've browsed the web/docs and cannot find out why this is not working.

I am trying to insert data (quotes) from a JSON file: 
    {

```
"quotesArray":[{
    "personName": "Albert Einstein",
    "quote": "Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better."
},
{
    "personName": "Stephen Hawking",
    "quote": "Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better."
},
{
    "personName": "Confucius",
    "quote": "Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated."
}]}
```

Into a simple HTML div using the following JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#realquote").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON('/json/quotes.json', function(data) {
     var html = " ";
       data.forEach(function(val) {
        var keys = Object.keys(val);
          html += "<div class = 'text-output'>";
            keys.forEach(function(key){ 
                html += val[key];

            });
               html += "</div>"
         });


       $(".realquote").html(html);
    });
   });          
   });
```

But every time, I get the error :TypeError: data.forEach is not a function" and I cannot figure out why.

If anyone could push me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `data` is a regular object that doesn't have `.forEach` method. You should iterate through the `quotesArray` property of the object.

```
data.quotesArray.forEach(fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `data.quotesArray` to actually access the array that you want to iterate through.

The `data` in the callback holds the object returned from your JSON file. Since plain Javascript object does not have `.forEach` method you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `data.quotesArray.forEach(..`  instead of  `data.forEach(..`

http://js.do/code/100647

If you want iterate through data then you can use `Object`

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key)
{

....

});
```